# Controlling redirection of CakePHP with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, post

I’ve installed cakePHP on Windows7+Apache2.2 and tried blog tutorial.

Now I’ve been confusing redirection control with .htaccess.

I’ve followed instruction of tutorial for setting .htaccess.

```
htdocs
  .htaccess
  app
    .htaccess
     webroot
        .htaccess
```

Eache .htaccess files are below.

[under htdocs]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

[under app]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

[under wabroot]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But error happens,here is message in error.log

```
client denied by server configuration: :/Apache2.2/htdocs/app/webroot/.htaccess
```

What’s wrong ?

This tutorial app uses following URLs.

```
http://mydomain/posts/index   // show index page
http://mydomain/posts/view/3  //show an article selected from index(3 means ID number)
http://mydomain/posts/add     //show a page for posting new articl
http://mydomain/posts/edit/3   //show a page for e
http://mydomain/posts/delete/3   //delete an article selected from index
```

`.htaccess` control redirection normally when URLs are /index and /view/3.

But if URLs are /`add` ,/`edit/3` and /`delete` apache doesn’t redirect them to `index.php`.

Actually operation for articles with `add` ,`edit` and `delete` are processed successfully.

And `add`,`edit` and `delete` use `POST` method

I guess if its method is POST redirection will be failure.

Comment: Last part of your question is not understandable... Could you please make it clear...

Comment: I’ve been trying this URL http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html. This program use `post`,`view`,`add`,`edit`and `delete` as operation for documents. Last part is describing which operations are redirected normally or no.

Comment: what is the headers of the request ?

Comment: I can’t see request header.
I mean I can’t print value of header variables because the request soon redirect to  `/app/webroot` directory and show files list under that directory.
`Index of /app/webroot
Parent Directory 
css/ 
favicon.ico 
files/ 
img/ 
index.php 
js/ `

Comment: I changed  `.htaccess` under `webroot` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-D  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f`. Now, It is redirected normally.But I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your folder structure is not seems good... You have to create a project name under htdocs and copy Cakephp files to that folder. Like-

```
htdocs
   --myapplication
      .htaccess
     -- app
          .htaccess
     -- webroot
          .htaccess
```

Comment: I pasted wrong list.I fixed the list in my question.